# Check if two MovieClips are the same?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I'm trying to check wether two MovieClips are of the same kind or not.

I have a collection of MovieClips stored in a dictionary, I'm then iterating over the entries and comparing each MovieClip with a MovieClip passed into the function. The problem is, it doesn't work. Neither does (==).

Any ideas?

Cheers.

```
    public function hideAllPagesExcept(activatedPage:MovieClip):void {
        for(var key:String in _navItems) {
            var mc:MovieClip = MovieClip(_navItems[key]);
            if(mc is activatedPage) {
                trace("Same");
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this doesn't work then the MovieClip you are passing in is not what you think it is.

```
public function hideAllPagesExcept(activatedPage:MovieClip):void {
    for each (var mc:MovieClip in _navItems) {
        if(mc == activatedPage) {
            trace("Same");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're right, I made a typo in the parameter I was passing ;) Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the way you are using the keys of the dictionary. Using `==` to check for equality is fine. The line `mc is activatedPage` is just wrong, the `is` operator is used to check the type of an object, like `mc is MovieClip`.

You are assuming the keys of the dictionary are Strings, which isn't always true. The point of a dictionary is that you can use any object as a key. If all you need are string based keys, use an Object.

By using `for(var key:String in _navItems)` you are converting the keys to strings, which leads to `mc` being `null`, because the key might look like `[object Object]` after the convertion and `_navItems["[object Object]"]` doesn't exist.

Either use `for(var key:Object in _navItems)` or use a *for each loop*, like The_asMan suggested. It iterates over the values of each key, instead of just over the keys.